# Function that returns #define value

Tags: xcode, function, methods, c-preprocessor

This is probably a weird way of coding, but I am trying to do it nonetheless.

I have a few defines:

```
#define kVar1 @"bla bla"
#define kVar2 @"wahey"
#define kVar3 @"Unicorn"
```

And in a method I'd like to call a function that returns either one of these kVar's.
Something like

```
    -(void)method {

    int i = 1 + arc4random() %10;   
unicorn.text = [self getVarValue:i];

    }
```

And I want to make getVarValue function, problem is I don't know how,
and no idea what keyword to search for in google either since I don't know
what is this thing called.

```
-(????)getVarValue:(int) i {

   switch(i) {
      case 1: return kVar1; break;
      case 2: return kVar2; break;
      case 3: return kVar3; break;
      default: return kVar1; break;

    }

}
```

What to put in that "????"
Does such thing even exist? Thanks

Comment: Remember that `#define`s are completely absorbed by the preprocessor.  All text substitution is done by the time the real compiler runs.  So your code is identical to as if you had done `case 1: return @"bla bla"; break;` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pointer to an `NSString`. You signature should look like `-(NSString *)getVarValue:(int) i`.